# continual update html display of js variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

So here is what I have by way of HTML

```
<div class="circle" >2000</div>
<div class="circle" >20</div>
```

and here is the CSS

```
.circle {
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   border:3px solid green;
   border-radius:250px;
   line-height:50px;
   text-align:center;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

I have a .js page that is a total list of all may variables for this game I am making.

What i am looking for is the ability to have each variable assigned a circle with a real-time/rapidly updating view of what the variables value is from the globalvars.js.

I read that it was possibly to do by including an id in the div like this
`<div class="circle" id=XXXXX></div>`
however I was unable to make this work and wanted to know if it was just me being stupid or something else. I am relatively new to programming so any and all constructive criticism is appreciated!

Comment: You can do this easily with AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with AngularJS [expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_expressions.asp). However, assuming you don't know AngularJS, here is a plain JS example:

Yes, you can add an `id` to the `<div>` much like you did with `class`.

```
<div id="display"></div>
```

Now, every time the variable updates, you can update the value of the `<div>` by selecting it with JS and changing its `innerHTML` property:

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = var_name;
```

For example, you can see this [simplistic example](http://jsfiddle.net/4hr01sfp/) on JSFiddle to see an example of how it works.

Comment: @Akmedrah And I'll post an example really soon to show you how.

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Akmedrah There it is! Just replace `random` with the variable of your choice and the `setInterval()` with whatever loop you use to update your variable.

Comment: so with this code 
`function woodClick(number){
    wood = wood + number;
    document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML = wood;
};`
I would use wood inplace of random

Comment: @Akmedrah does that work? If it does, please accept. If not, feedback please?

Comment: yes it works sorry i fell asleep right after testing it.

Answer (score 0):

create a function update. update the properties using `document.getElementById("elementID").innerHTML = variable` inside that function. I prefer using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` as it allows for user-interactions as well in-between.